# MySQL subtracting value from one table by some rows from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have 2 tables
players:

```
| ID | PLAYER | WARNINGS |
|----|--------|----------|
|  1 |      a |       35 |
|  2 |      b |       70 |
|  3 |      c |       65 |
```

warns:

```
| ID | PLAYER | POWER | ACTIVE |       TIMEEND |
|----|--------|-------|--------|---------------|
|  1 |      a |     5 |      1 | 1388051312120 |
|  2 |      a |    10 |      1 | 1388051312120 |
|  3 |      a |    20 |      1 | 1388051312120 |
|  4 |      b |    30 |      1 | 1388051312120 |
|  5 |      b |    40 |      1 | 1388051312120 |
|  6 |      c |    10 |      1 | 1388051312120 |
|  7 |      c |    55 |      1 | 1388051312120 |
```

And I want check every row from `warns` where `warns.active=1`, and then if `warns.timeend <= NOW()` remove (subtract) a `warns.power` from `players.warnings` of `player` and change `warns.active=2`

So after that tables must look like this:

players:

```
| ID | PLAYER | WARNINGS |
|----|--------|----------|
|  1 |      a |        0 |
|  2 |      b |        0 |
|  3 |      c |        0 |
```

warns:

```
| ID | PLAYER | POWER | ACTIVE |       TIMEEND |
|----|--------|-------|--------|---------------|
|  1 |      a |     5 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  2 |      a |    10 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  3 |      a |    20 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  4 |      b |    30 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  5 |      b |    40 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  6 |      c |    10 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  7 |      c |    55 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
```

I only have that:
`UPDATE players,warns SET warns.Active=2, players.Warnings=players.Warnings-warns.Power WHERE (warns.Active=1) AND (warns.TimeEnd <= NOW()) AND (warns.Player=players.Player);`
But that giving me:

players:

```
| ID | PLAYER | WARNINGS |
|----|--------|----------|
|  1 |      a |       30 |
|  2 |      b |       40 |
|  3 |      c |       55 |
```

warns:

```
| ID | PLAYER | POWER | ACTIVE |       TIMEEND |
|----|--------|-------|--------|---------------|
|  1 |      a |     5 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  2 |      a |    10 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  3 |      a |    20 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  4 |      b |    30 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  5 |      b |    40 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  6 |      c |    10 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
|  7 |      c |    55 |      2 | 1388051312120 |
```

So subtract only first row of every player...
Any ideas how to fix that?
And sorry for my bad English! I hope you understand me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE players P 
INNER JOIN (SELECT W.PLAYER, SUM(W.POWER) WARNING
            FROM WARNS W WHERE W.active = 1 AND W.timeend <= NOW()
            GROUP BY W.PLAYER 
           ) A ON P.PLAYER = A.PLAYER
SET P.WARNINGS = P.WARNINGS - A.WARNING ;

UPDATE WARNS 
SET active = 2
WHERE active = 1 AND timeend <= NOW();
```

Comment: Hyym, nope ;/ player `a` have -135, `b` have 70 and `c` have 65. (so all points are subtracted from player `a` ;/)

Comment: @user2250333 Check my updated answer. It will resolve your issue. I forgot to put GROUP BY in INNER QUERY

Comment: OH! Thanks :) That works great... I must learn more about SQL syntax... :D So thanks!

Comment: Hyym, Hi! That possible to get list (ResultSet) of players where "WARNINGS" was changed? (I writing that in Java)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite just updates a table at once.

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE players SET warnings=warnings - (SELECT SUM(power) FROM warns WHERE id=players.id AND DATETIME(??? TimeEnd ???) <= DATETIME('NOW') AND active=1);
UPDATE warns SET active=2 WHERE DATETIME(??? TimeEnd ???) <= DATETIME('NOW') AND active=1;
COMMIT;
```

What kind of `TimeEnd` is this?

However, I would suggest you an alternate approach (without redundant data):

```
TABLE: players (ID, Player);
TABLE: warns (ID, POWER, TIMEEND);
VIEW: active_warnings = SELECT ID, Player, COALESCE(SUM(Power),0)
                        FROM Player
                        LEFT JOIN warns USING(ID)
                        WHERE DATETIME(??? TimeEnd ???) <= DATETIME('NOW')
                        GROUP BY Id;
```

Comment: TimeEnd is time in milliseconds from java - It's easier to use it from (java) code.